# Calculate bandwidth for retrieving webpage through Tor

Tags: android, performance, tor

I need to calculate the total bandwidth retrieving a webpage takes through Tor in android. In my android app, I create a Tor circuit using the Tor library and retrieves the webpage and then close the Tor circuit. How can I get the total bandwidth (Tor circuit creation + request sent + response received)?
Is it possible to calculate the total bandwidth theoretically, if we know the bandwidth without Tor?

```
       int port = onionProxyManager.getIPv4LocalHostSocksPort();

        int proxyPort = port;
        String proxyHost = "127.0.0.1";
        String remoteHost = "google.com";
        int remotePort = 80;

        Socks5Proxy socks5Proxy = new Socks5Proxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        socks5Proxy.resolveAddrLocally(false);

        Socket socket = new SocksSocket(socks5Proxy, remoteHost, remotePort);
        BufferedReader dIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream dOut = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String str = null;
        do {
            str = dIn.readLine();
            response = response + str;
        } while (str != null);
        onionProxyManager.stop();
```

Tried Network profiler as suggested by JensV below. I couldn't find total data usage using the network profiler. Is there anything I'm missing? I have added the screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible. I'm assuming that you're using [this library](https://github.com/thaliproject/Tor_Onion_Proxy_Library) (inferred from your code). I looked at the source of the library and to create tor proxy, it actually [spawns a separate process](https://github.com/thaliproject/Tor_Onion_Proxy_Library/blob/74407114cbfa8ea6f2ac51417dda8be98d8aba86/universal/src/main/java/com/msopentech/thali/toronionproxy/OnionProxyManager.java#L450) which launches the tor binary.

So while technically somehow possible, the library offers no way of intercepting/inspecting the packets (or packet size) itself.

If you just want to do inspections, you can use the Network Profiler in Android Studio. There you should be able to see how much traffic is being done. You could also collect data this way and approximate how much overhead you have from basic network requests and show an estimate to the user.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried the network profiler but couldn't get it to work. I still can't find total data usage. network profiler is giving limited functionality to me here. Do you have any suggestions? I also added a screenshot in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wifi hotspot on your laptop and connect to it via the android phone. From the laptop, you install wireshark to analyze the TOR traffic. If you type in google "setup wifi hotspot Ubuntu", you find a lot of example to set this up. And the same for Wireshark and tor traffic.